# Generating a random turtle function in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function called randomTurtle():

- generate a random number between 0 and 100
  (0 and 100 included) that will determine the total number of moves the turtle will make (in other words, how many times the turtle will loop through)

Then For each repetition of the sequence):
Generate a random number of steps between 1 and 50 (1 and 50 included).

Move the turtle forward by that amount.

Select a random float between 0 and 1. If the value is less than 0.5, turn the turtle right. If the value is greater than or equal to 0.5, turn the turtle left

Comment: "Move the turtle forward by that amount." - how should this look like?

Comment: Did you check the Python standard library? http://docs.python.org/library/ Also, is that a homework?

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import random

moves = randint(0, 101)
for i in xrange(moves):
  steps = randint(1, 51)
  moveTurtle(direction, steps)
  spin = random()
  if spin < 0.5:
    direction = turn_right(direction)
  else:
    direction = turn_left(direction)

def turn_left(direction):
  #returns your new direction if you start facing 'direction' and turn left
def turn_right(direction):
  #returns your new direction if you start facing 'direction' and turn right
def moveTurtle(direction, steps)
  #moves turtle in 'direction' by 'steps'
```